# How do I combine these two Select queries with an OR case

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all rows where `WHERE (uid = {$uid} OR uid = **HERE** )` where `**HERE**` is the `cid`s retreived from query 2 below.

Query 1:

```
    SELECT * FROM `t_activities`
    WHERE (`uid` = {$uid} OR `uid` = **HERE** )
    AND `del` = 0
    GROUP BY `fid`
    ORDER BY `time` DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

And Query 2:

```
SELECT `cid` FROM `t_con` WHERE `uid` = {$uid} AND `flag` = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `t_activities`
WHERE (`uid` = {$uid} OR `uid` in (SELECT `cid` 
                                   FROM `t_con` 
                                   WHERE `uid` = {$uid} AND `flag` = 1))
AND `del` = 0
GROUP BY `fid`
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What is this method called? I was looking for 'Joins', 'left join', 'Inner join' etc but wasn't able to figure out. Thanks it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a join as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t_activities` ta left outer join
     (SELECT `cid` 
      FROM `t_con` 
      WHERE `uid` = {$uid} AND `flag` = 1)
     ) tc
     on ta = tc.cid
WHERE (`uid` = {$uid} OR tc.`uid` is not null) AND `del` = 0
GROUP BY `fid`
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

By the way, as a SQL statement the "GROUP BY fid" looks very strange.  This is allowed in mysql, but I think it is a bad practice.  It is much better to be explicit about what you are doing:

```
SELECT fid, min(<field1>) as Field1, . . .
```

This helps prevent mistakes when you go back to the query or try to modify it.